# Как скрыть домен в Url-ссылке перед go.php?

Tags: javascript, php, шифрование, base64, urlencode

Задача такая: нужно скрыть название домена во внешней ссылке, которая открывается через свой go.php файл.

Сейчас вид ссылок такой:

```
<a href="http://domen.ru/go.php?site=1"><img src="http://domen.ru/img/photo.jpg"></a>
```

Нужно сделать такой:

```
 <a href="/go.php?site=1"><img src="/img/photo.jpg"></a>
```

Может кто-то привести пример php-кода, как зашифровать название домена используя base64_encode или что-то другое, типа urlencode, возможно есть готовый JavaScript. Полезна будет любая информация по реализации этой задачи, так как, я чайник. Поисковики мне ничем не помогли. Может где-то и есть описанные примеры, но я не смог их найти.

Answer (score 1):

От кого вы хотите спрятать этот домен? От пользователя или роботов?

А вообще вот варианты:

- Использовать сервис коротких ссылок (goo.gl, vk.cc) и т.д
- Использовать проксирующий сервер
- Писать любой домен, но при обработке onckick() по ссылке джаваскриптом менять на нужное. (а вдруг у пользователя будет выключен js?)

Answer (score 0):

Сложная задача для того кто не владеет знаниями php кодирования. Лучше отказаться от этой затеи. Только время зря тратить впустую. Таким кодированием занимаются авторитетные дядьки которые не выкладывают свои примеры кода в публичный доступ.
Можно было-бы попробовать закодировать одно фото но тогда скорее всего редирект go.php не отобразит картинку с такой ссылкой: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS`